# How do I set up a for loop with multiple arrays as variables to serve as text in a marker in Swift 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, mapbox

I have multiple arrays that I want to iterate over and plug in as values later in my code for markers on a map. I have the markers populated but can't figure out how to apply the text marker title and subtitle to the marker associated with the location.

iOS and Swift 2

edit: using Mapbox iOS SDK as well.

How do I write the for loop that will do this?

My code trimmed down so far.

Arrays taken from geojson file:

```
//place variable to array of strings
var place = [String]()
//result from this array ["park", "playground", "parking"]

//pass variable to array of strings
var pass = [String]()
//result from this array ["True", "False", ""]
```

I have also done this with latitude and longitude but won't add that here. But I do need to add the for loop for it.

```
//lat and long is served and then all the r,z points, then another lat, long...need to fix this and it may work...
        for var (i,x) in zip(lat, long) {
            print(i)
            print(x)
            //print(i + ", " + x)

        // String to double conversion
        let lati = NSString(string: i).doubleValue
        let longi = NSString(string: x).doubleValue

        var point = MGLPointAnnotation()
            point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lati, longitude: longi)

            let r = place
            print(r)
            point.title = r
            print(r)

            let z = pass
            print(z)
            point.subtitle = z

        mapView.addAnnotation(point)
        }
```

So the markers are all added correctly to the map based on lat and long. The marker text however is only added once, and uses the last record served. I am betting I am missing something simple here, as I am newish to coding with Swift 2.

I am receiving this error message "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'" associated with this line "point.title = r" and this line "point.subtitle = z" which complicates things.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

If you need more information I can edit as needed but hopefully you have everything you need to help me set up this for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the data type of title and subtitle in point.title and point.subtitle respectively?
You are assigning a ***String Array*** place to r. Whereas, point.title is not an array type. I'm still missing your question on where do you want to add the loop?

Comment: They both should receive text strings, but the text strings are in individual arrays, place and pass. geojson is where I have fetched the value I want in other code (not listed) but there are 105 records in the array. Each array is connected based on the order they are in to the other arrays. I need to apply a for loop through the different arrays record after record and take the value and plug that in lati, longi, place and pass. So i, x, r and z. That help?

Comment: Are there 105 lat long pairs as well? Corresponding to which you want place and pass?

Comment: Declare var index = 0 before for loop in your code. After mapview.addannotation increment the index by 1 (index += 1). Assign the title as point.title = place[index]

Comment: yes to your first comment. I was wondering if I could index it...I'll give it a shot, might be tomorrow before I respond..

Comment: for whatever reason that did not work...it didn't like that I was trying to add an int after place...I now have 3 for loops in a row that I hope will work...we shall see..